# h264 high profile video: playback from specified point

Tags: indexing, decode, h.264

## What is the proper and fast way to start streaming/playback of h264 high profile HDTV video dump from the specific point?

Huge sample of the real life stream:  [this](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4382917) file.

According to 'ffprobe -show_frames' this sample 10Gb 105 minutes video dump has only 28 video frames marked as 'key_frame=1' and 10 I-frames.

Application which I am trying to improve uses such frames as some kind of index, allowing to rewind and play from any key-frame or I-frame.
It works perfectly with other streams. But not in this case, as you can easily understand. Only 28 starting points of playback in 100+ minutes of show is far too low.

I've checked the presence of packets with 'random-access-indicator' enabled - but such packets in this stream aren't on frame boundaries, they don't have 'frame begin' bit enabled, so I can't rely on them.
Is there a way at all to implement 'rewind/pause/play from the specified time point' feature for this codec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by interpretation as index frames the ones which contain NAL sequences 'nal slice idr' and 'nal slice pps'.